# How can we have multiple "exact" tests?

Tags: statistical-power, fishers-exact-test, frequentist

Looking over the differences between Fisher's exact test and Barnard's test, it seems I'm missing something fundamental. If both are exact tests, shouldn't both give the exact and identical value for $P(data | H_0)$, in this case $P(data | p_{r1} = p_{r2})$?

Comment: You might add Boschloo's test to your question.

Comment: It's possible the that the description of these tests in Wikipedia answers the question.  ( [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boschloo%27s_test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boschloo%27s_test) ;  [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnard%27s_test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnard%27s_test) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really; all an exact test needs to do is accept or reject the null hypothesis based on the actual distribution of the test statistic.  Consider the following two tests of whether the mean of a Normal distribution with known standard deviation equals zero.

1. A z-test for whether the mean $= 0$.  No explanation needed!
2. A binomial test for whether the mean (= the median) $= 0$.  Here we assume the probability of an observation being above the median $= 0.5$; this is an exact test, as the binomial distribution with probability $0.5$ is the true distribution of the number of observations above the median.

These two tests will (almost) certainly give different results when calculating the probability of the observed data under the null hypothesis, but they are both exact.

Expanding on this example to address a comment:

The key here is that, although the underlying distribution is the same in both cases, the test statistics $T_N(x)$ and $T_B(x)$ are not (regardless of whether the null hypothesis is true.)  There is no 1-1 map between the two (this is important.)  Consequently, $p(x|T_N(x))$ and $p(x|T_B(x))$ aren't guaranteed to be the same either.  The underlying distributions are the same; the distributions conditional upon the test statistic are not.

However, *conditional upon the test results failing to reject the null hypothesis*, in both cases we have the "estimated" mean $= 0$ and standard deviation $= 1$.  Consequently, $p(x|H_0, T_N(x)) = p(x|H_0, T_B(x))$; the test statistic is irrelevant as the distribution is fully determined (in this case) by $H_0$.  In the more general case where we have parameters $\theta$ that are not specified by the hypotheses and therefore need to be estimated, as long as a) the estimation procedure is the same regardless of the test chosen, and b) neither test rejects the null hypothesis, we have $p(x|H_0, \hat{\theta}, T_1(x)) = p(x|H_0, \hat{\theta}, T_2(x)) = p(x|H_0, \hat{\theta})$.

Comment: I see the analogy, and this makes perfect sense, but the underlying philosophy is confusing. In a frequentist interpretation, the probability of something should be measurable. If I take two equal normal variables and sample them, the results of $P(X|H_0)$ will converge to a single number, not two.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your point.

Answer (score 12):

What make and exact test *exact* is that it uses the actual distributions of the null hypothesis (e.g. binomial or hypergeometric or multinomial distributions) rather than approximations (e.g. normal or chi-square distributions) to calculate $p$-values of the probability of seeing the observed result or another result as or more extreme.

Since they often involve discrete distributions, they usually do not have a critical region with probability exactly equal to some pre-specified significance level $\alpha$, causing some further confusion over the word *exact*.

Different tests have different distributions underlying the null hypothesis: the Fisher test assumes a hypergeometric distribution while Barnard's test assumes two binomial distributions.  This means that they usually calculate different $p$-values.  Some tests may also have different views of what counts as *more extreme*.  So different tests should not be expected to give the same results, and this is a reason why you should decide which test to use before you see the data.

Comment: Ignore the significance level. The actual probability should be a single number. If there are two ways of modeling the data as @jbowman described above, they still should in theory give the same result.

Comment: @nbubis The calculated probabilities depends on the assumed distributions under the null hypothesis (and on what counts as extreme).  If these are different in different tests then you will get different calculations.  For example, in the "lady tasting tea" case of $8$ cups of which $4$ had milk put in first, Ronald Fisher calculated that the probability of Muriel Bristol getting all $8$ correct with no skill was $\frac1{8\choose 4} =\frac1{70}$, while assuming each guess was independent would have given $\left(\frac{4}{8}\right)^8 =\frac1{256}$ and other assumptions yet different values

Comment: @nbubis - as my example shows, if there are two ways of modeling the data, there is no theoretical reason they should give the same result, except under specific conditions (e.g., the two ways are essentially transformations of each other, such as Poisson arrivals and Exponential interarrival times.)

Answer (score 7):

1. The answer mostly  comes down to definition. An exact test is one that when the assumptions it makes under $H_0$ hold, will not exceed the selected type I error rate (anywhere under the null), at any given sample size [1].

   For a point null (almost all the tests you're likely to be doing in pactice) it should equal the desired type I error rate if that is chosen from the available rates. With a discrete test statistic there's a finite (or perhaps countable) set of  choices unless you use randomized tests.

   Unsurprisingly given such a broad definition,  there's an infinite number of exact tests. For example, most common rank based tests are exact (given the earlier caveats).

   While the usual chi-squared test of independence is not small-sample exact, it is possible to construct an exact test using that statistic (indeed it's an option in R's `chisq.test` to do that exact test, at least as accurately as you're prepared to simulate, though you can in principle to a perfectly exact test by complete enumeration of the tails, or via the use of clever algorithms to achieve the same outcome).

   In the same fashion, one could construct an exact test based on the G statistic or the Neyman statistic or the Freeman-Tukey statistic, or any of the other Cressie-Reed power-divergence statistics, or indeed any number of other possibilities, all for the same contingency table and under the same assumptions and the same conditioning on the margins - an infinite array of possible tests just for independence in  contingency tables.

   Note that Barnard's test [2] does not condition on both margins, so it would be part of another group of tests again.
2. A small clarification is needed (I presume you understood this already but the phrasing in the question may mislead some readers).

   Hypothesis tests don't
   evaluate $P(\text{data}|H_0)$, since significance levels are based on the probability that the test statistic will fall into the rejection region (and thence the '*as, or more extreme*' phrasing for p values). Generally the test will have an explicit test statistic whose cdf can be computed exactly (at least in principle, and to any required degree of accuracy in practice) and hence explicit rejection rules obtained. From this an  exact p value will be implied. E.g. for tests where you would reject for small values of the test statistic (say T), $P(T\leq t_\text{obs})$ is the p value, and different tests will not order the possible samples the same way (e.g. an exact test based on a chi squared statistic and a Fisher exact test will not always perfectly correspond).  While a test statistic is often not given for the Fisher exact test, it is possible to define one, even in $r\times c$ tables.

   For that test, since that effective statistic is based on likelihood under the null, you could indeed consider $\text{data}|H_0$, but '*as or more extreme*' includes all other tables [2] with equal or lower probability, not just that specific data table.

---

[1]: Further, since we don't know that the exact form of population distributions hold, typically people don't use the phrase 'exact' when there's a specific distributional form assumed (that doesn't follow from the other assumptions). However, given the assumption, many such tests will be exact when the assumptions all hold.

[2]: A few years later (edit: it was in a paper published in 1949) Barnard came to the conclusion that Fisher had been correct to condition in this situation. In a 1988 interview with de Groot (in Statistical Science) Barnard describes what led to his change of mind (in effect a Socratic question from Fisher).

[3]: ... with the same margins, since the test conditions on the margins. However, the test does not require one to have fixed margins  (as many texts incorrectly state).

Comment: The "does not exceed" makes the test "exact" only in a strange sense, so I always quote the word "exact" when referring to Fisher's test.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your input. With a point null it's exact if you choose only from the available significance levels. For a composite null (say a one tailed test in the $2\times 2$ case) you *can't* make it exact over the whole of the null space, only at a specific place or subset of places (by the most common convention, the place(s) where type I error is largest). I'm happy to say *exact* as long as it's clear in what sense it achieves the claimed exactness. On the other hand, I'm happy to say 'exact' if there's a high chance people will miss the explanation of that sense.

Comment: I strongly encourage people to actually spend the small amount of effort to compute their available significance levels with discrete test statistics (at least to a high degree of accuracy by simulation if nothing else), because I have on a disturbingly large number of occasions seen people doing tests where their *exact* significance level ended up at 0, and the only hint that many of them seem to get is a growing unease that none of their p-values ever seem to be less than 0.05. If you're doing Mann=Whitney with n=m=3 or Wilcoxon signed rank tests with 3 pairs, ... this is you.

Comment: Similarly if you're using $\alpha$ at $\frac12\%$ (as some people do now) or doing lots of multiple comparisons, those sample sizes may then be larger than three and there might still be no chance of a rejection.